# Accessing viewmodel from another viewmodel in durandaljs is creating a new instance instead of accessing the singleton instance

Tags: javascript, requirejs, single-page-application, durandal

I have a div element in my shell.html that uses the compose binding to load a view and view model:

```
<div data-bind="compose: { model: 'viewmodels/subMenu' }"></div>
```

My shell.js looks like:

```
import common = require("helpers/common");

class Shell { 
    view: any; router: DurandalRootRouter; 
    activate: () => Q.Promise<any>; 
    constructor() { 
        var self = this; 
        self.view = common.view; 
        self.router = common.router; 
        common.router.map([ { route: '', title: 'Home', moduleId: 'viewmodels/Home', nav: true } ]);
        self.activate = () => { return Q.when(common.router.activate()); }
     } 
}

export = Shell
```

My subMenu.js view model looks like the following:

```
define([], function () {
    "use strict";
    return {
        isPreview: ko.observable(false)
    };
});
```

I then have another view model which imports this subMenu viewmodel with requirejs and changes the 'isPreview' property value. But when it imports the submenu view model, it creates a new instance rather than accessing the existing one. Based on the durandal docs: http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Creating-A-Module.html

> In the above example, both modules returned an object instance. This results in what would commonly be called a "singleton" object, since the same object instance is obtained by all who require it.

I understand that because it returns an object this should therefore be the same instance instead of being transient?

Comment: Can you post your shell viewmodel's code?